# Python Multiprocessing: How to set up the number of max_workers properly?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, large-data

Background: I have a huge DataFrame with 40 million rows. I have to run some functions on some columns. The loops were taking too long, so I decided to go with Multiprocessing. 
CPU: 8 cores 16 threads
RAM: 128 GB

Question: How many chunks should I break the data into? And how many workers are properly for this dataset?

p.s. I found out that when I set the max_workers = 15, all threads are running 100%. But if I change the max_workers to 40, they dropped to 40%.

Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, the worker number corresponding to the thread numbers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of parallel computing. Those are  io-intensive, cpu-intensive and io-cpu intensive computing.
If your thread is runing on cpu-intensive  task, then You can increase your worker numbers as you want to get better performance.
But If it is runing on io-intensive, it willl no effect to increase them.

You seems to be working on io-cpu intensive task.
So If you increase worker numbers, you can get good result until there is no competition for using io resource(hard disk)
so In local machine . it is not a good choice to increase worker numbers.

You can use Hadoop on GPS or AWS for this work.